# Are Rivers and Aquifers guaranteed to come together in Dwarf Fortress?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I've been interested in Dwarf Fortress, so I decided to start playing with it. It has a reputation for being quite difficult, so I decided to find a tutorial. **Every** tutorial I found recommended to start by a river, and not to start by an aquifer.

So, I started the game, generated my world, and what do I find? Every single area with a river, also has an aquifer. Are these tied together?

If it helps, I am running the latest version (0.31.10).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, they're not guaranteed to come together, at least not when considering a brook the same as a river. A brook is easier for beginners to start with, and has the same benefits as a river.

I usually use the following settings in the <kbd>f</kbd>ind dialog to find a good place for starters:

- Evil: Medium
- Temperature: Medium
- Rain: Medium
- Flux Stone: Yes
- Aquifer: No
- River: Yes

You might also want to read [my reponse on the question for a good starting location](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/962/picking-first-fortress-location-in-dwarf-fortress/982#982) for beginners.

Comment: The only benefit a brook lacks is being a barrier to invaders :(

Answer (score 2):

I know you can find brooks in areas that do not also have aquifers. In fact, brooks are easier to work with because they can be walked over, so I really recommend them over rivers for starting with.

If you can't find a good starting area (there's a lot of places to look, don't give up too soon!) you might have generated a difficult world. You can always regenerate.